# Where does the translation came from? Java servlet, tomcat and Ext-Js Sencha application

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, extjs

I got a Freelancer work and now I am with some problems with the application. I was going to translate it to portuguese using jQuery and the unique ids of the elements. However I have some doubts about it. 
I had no idea about the ExtJs and I read about it, then some questions came up:

- Is the translation saved on a database?
- Each field of the menu is saved on a database?
- I realized that due the dinamic content loading the ids can be different everytime that day are loaded, is that true?

I know that the best way to translate it is not the one I've proposed. I thought about it before I see the code because I was thinking that it was a normal website. I already added the option of the Portuguese language on the login screen. However it sends the "pt" parameter and doesn't loads anything. It goes back to the default "en". The language parameter is send to a file Home.java where the doGet function is called. I couldn't find any file with the translation of it. Anyone can help me? I don't know how to do it (Load the menu in Portuguese). Thank you.

the website is:
http://brazil.chatlibs.com:81/bulkmessaging/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way out for this. I did some translations for an ExtJS app and all I had was a JS class file with all the strings for both languages.

Then at application startup I'd call something like `customStringsClass.setLocale('en')`. This method would set `customStringsClass.Labels`, for example, to an object containing all the strings for the english language.

Then in controllers and views, I'd use `customStringsClass.Labels.FirstNameField_Label`

Comment: I looked for something with the language on it and I didn't find nothing. I am using a MacBook and searched for the arabic word. I could find a lot of files based on its content using the Mac search tool. Also I googled for this function (customStringClass) and I didn't find anything. Is this Java or Javascript? Or a ExtJS function? I am totally noob on it. I want to learn because I loved the idea of dinamic form load. Thank you!

Comment: @JaquelinePassos When I meant "no easy way out", it's what it meant. You'll have to create the code, hire a translator, etc. I would recommend you trying out something more specific first then come back,